# Deorbit of ISS is a unique event. Are there plans for scientific observation?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, debris

The ISS deorbit will be unique. Not only because of its mass, but because the time, location and observing conditions can be accurately chosen. Instruments could be placed for detailed observation. What should be studied and what preparations should be made?

Comment: How is this different from other de-orbits, like MIR or Tiangong-2?

Comment: @Polygnome, ISS is x4 MIR and x40 Tiangong-2 in mass. I assume this alone will be spectacular for an atmosphere reentry. Another difference is that it's truly an international satellite falling back. From a legal point of view, any damage it's debris may create on Earth is interesting.